# Managing project config files in repository

Tags: git, github, configuration-files

I have some questions about managing config files in git repo.

**Question 1:** Suppose we have `.env` in master that looks like this (variables just declared but not defined!):

```
XXX_CLIENT_ID=
XXX_SECRET=
```

Then someone pull master, create local branch, change `.env`, do some commits and then wants merge to master. How can master branch omits changing in `.env` file during merge? Is `git update-index --assume-unchanged` solves this or may be we can handle it better?

**Question 2:** OK, let's look situation when we want share config in our team, for example `.dev.env`. Like in *Question 1* in master we have file similar like `.env` without values but we want share it in team and it should be secret for public because master still public. It looks like `git-secret` do this job but I want hear what are you using today for solving this problem.

Any good idea or best practices how you manage it in your team?

Answer (score 0):

For question 1:
A good practice is to separate code and configuration. I.e in the repository that holds your code you have a `.env.sample` file that specifies what config variables the application expects to be set (possibly with default values).
People cloning or branching out from master locally can then specify their property values in a `.env` file that is added to `.gitignore` and thus not impacting the git tree. When the application is tested locally by the developer it uses the configuration in the `.env`, which is specific to the environment of the developer.

This way you can keep a `.env.sample` file in master indicating to the public what config is needed, but cloners need to specify their own `.env` for their local environment

A developer only edits the `.env.sample` file if config is added/removed (which is information that needs to be merged back to master)