# Any idea to controlling setting files?

Tags: git, github, secret-key

I make a program that has next file system:

```
-.git/
-main.py
-setting.json
...
```

First, I upload the **default** setting.json to github repository.

Then changing setting.json for testing, but i don't want to push the changed setting.json.

Now, i am using just

```
git add filname
```

for changed code.

Is it the best leaving the setting.json on modified state? setting.json needs to write secret key in the file.

Comment: Here is another suggestion for how to handle config files containing secrets: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40550975/7146596

Comment: Use a sample file that you track and ignore the real file. That's the usual technique.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I put making default setting file code in the main code.